# Layers intersecting each other with 3D Layer (after effects)

Tags: layers, 3d, adobe-after-effects

I have two layers, one for red bar, and another for the photograph. The red bar is above the photograph, but when i animate with 3D Layer, both layers intersect each other.

[image]

The photograph is going up, red bar is going down. My problem is this intersection (yellow arrow).

How can i put the photograph always behind the red bar and avoid this intersection?

My suggestion: I cut the photograph, but the result is not satisfactory. Is there another way?

Thank you!

Answer (score 2):

I solved!

Just add a command layer between the two layers that are intersecting. (blue rectangle). It work fine for me. Thank you Filipi!

[image]

Answer (score 1):

I do not know how, but it works!
Thank you Filipi!

This layer can be removed behind the scene and put 1% opacity on it - this is the most common shape rectangle.
[image]